# how to do alphabetical ordering in python using for and while loop?

Tags: python, loops, do-while

Write a code in python to write aphabets and also try to do this in under looping with do-while or for loop

Tried lot but can't solve it . i have done by using for loop and do whilw but i cant known how to write alphabets in order

Comment: Have you created any code? If yes please add it to your question

Comment: What do you mean by "write alphabets"?  Can you show what the output you are expecting is?

Comment: Please show the code you've tried and maybe reword your question in English

Answer (score 0):

- first you need to import `string`
- `string.ascii_lowercase` is a constant from the string module in Python. It represents the lowercase letters of the alphabet, and it's value is a string that contains all 26 lowercase letters of the alphabet in order. as follows:

  ```
    import string
    print(string.ascii_lowercase)


    output ------> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  ```

**This is the full code for your question**

```
import string

alphabets = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
for letter in alphabets:
    print(letter)
```